Time-scale of energy transfer between vibration modes?
Consider N (roughly 3 to 10) particles interacting by Lennard-Jones potential having given total energy E and simulated in vacuum. Initially they form some cluster and they vibrate roughly at the Lennard-Jones equilibrium distance. As time goes on, the "Lennard-Jones bonds" are exchanging energy and so some bonds may vibrate stronger and other vibrate weaker. At some point a specific bond may aquire enough energy to be broken, such that two particles initially at Lennard-Jones equiblrium will go apart.
How much time does it take to see this ? How much time does the energy of this Lennard-Jones "molecule" need to be redistributed in such way that bond dissociation is observed ?
Literature hints would be highly appreciated.
